# Can I provide context values using a function in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I am currently asking myself the following question:
Is it recommended that I define my state and logic directly in the ContextProvider or is it okay if I define the state and logic in a separate function to separate the code a bit?

Example:

```
const MyContext = React.createContext({});

const createStore = () => {
    const [myState, setMyState] = useState();
    return {
       myState,
       setMyState
    }
}

const MyContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const store = createStore();
  return (
     <MyContext.Provider value={store}>{children}</MyContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

I am a little bit affraid of that `createStore` function. Does the createStore always gets recreated if the Provider rerenders ?

Edit:
Thanks for the answer!

What if I want to use a parameter in the `useCreateStore` hook ?
Will the parameter gets updated?

Example:

```
const MyContext = React.createContext({});

const useCustomStore= (myAwesomeValue) => {
    const [myState, setMyState] = useState();

   const doSomething = useCallback(() => {
      //
   }, [myAwesomeValue])

    return {
       myState,
       setMyState
    }
}

const MyContextProvider = ({ children, title }) => {
  const { myState } = useCustomStore(title); //You need to desctructure the returned object here, note myState
  return (
     <MyContext.Provider value={myState}>{children}</MyContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to create for your "store" is called a [custom hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html)

You will need to make some changes though. It is customary to use 'use' as the start of a custom hook. so, here I have renamed `createStore` to `useCustomStore`. Since it is a custom hook with useState, it follows the same rules as if you actually had it within your context provider

Also, your custom hook returns an object which contains the state and a mutation method. you will need to access the state either directly `store.myState` or you can destructure it `{ myState}` as I have in the example.

```
const MyContext = React.createContext({});

const useCustomStore= () => {
    const [myState, setMyState] = useState();
    return {
       myState,
       setMyState
    }
}

const MyContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const { myState } = useCustomStore(); //You need to desctructure the returned object here, note myState
  return (
     <MyContext.Provider value={myState}>{children}</MyContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Is the same as

```
const MyContext = React.createContext({});
  
const MyContextProvider = ({ children }) => {

  const [myState, setMyState] = useState();

  return (
     <MyContext.Provider value={myState}>{children}</MyContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

So rerenders will preserve state, since it uses the useState hook.

Comment: Thanks you for the clear answer :) I already thought that I have to prefix it with `use`, because React is doing some magic under the hood with that prefix.

Comment: You don't need to use the `use` prefix, you can all the custom hook whatever you like.. its just "good practice" to do so. Yes, you should pass an initial state into the hook `useState(initialState)`, and then mutate the state using the `setMyState` mutation method provided by the useState hook

Comment: I have edited my main post and added a different question. I was not able to post code in this comment section here